# How to build a textarea with character counter and max length?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Please consider [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpbWY/). It contains something along these lines:

```html
<textarea data-bind="value: comment, valueUpdate: 'afterkyedown'"></textarea>

<br/><br/>
<span data-bind="text: getCount, valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']"></span> characters???
```

And this JavaScript:

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.count = ko.observable(0);
    self.comment = ko.observable("");
    self.getCount = function(){
        var countNum = 10 - self.comment().length;
        self.count(countNum);
    };
}

var viewModel12 = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I have a textarea where the maxlength should be 20 characters. When the number of characters reaches 20, it will be stop, and if you try to add more characters, they will be removed.

Note that this also has to work for copy/paste: if a user pastes more than 20 characters, only the first 20 will stay, and the rest of them should be removed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26503523/118153 is a decent solution.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpbWY/3/), which works along these lines:

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.comment = ko.observable("");
    self.count = ko.computed(function(){
        var countNum = 10 - self.comment().length;
        return countNum
    });
}

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<textarea data-bind="value: comment, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></textarea>
<br/><br/>
<span data-bind="text: count"></span> characters​​​​​​​
```

You need to learn about [ko.computed()](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to do this sort of stuff...

Comment: thank you. still  need help to limit the text to only 20 characters.  I still able to type more than 20 in the textarea.

Answer (score 7):

Using a computed value only partially solves the problem. Disabling the textarea based on that computed value (as was done in [Michael Berkompas's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpbWY/5/)) doesn't really solve the problem. You need to use a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) to make this work. Using that fiddle as a starting point, we can use custom bindings to round it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/ReQrz/1/

Which is something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.limitCharacters = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel)
    {
       element.value = element.value.substr(0, valueAccessor());
       allBindingsAccessor().value(element.value.substr(0, valueAccessor()));
    }
};
```

And then doing:

```
<textarea data-bind="value: comment, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', limitCharacters: 20"></textarea>
```

Comment: Awesome solution, however it doesn't work in KnockoutJS 3.0.  Any idea why?

Comment: @BrianDavidBerman, no clue. I stopped using Knockout in favor of Angular and haven't looked back.

Comment: I had a look at it with KnockoutJS 3.0. Here's the fiddle for that one: http://jsfiddle.net/R3Pxf/

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in 3.0.0

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.maxLength = {
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings){
            if(allBindings().value()){
                allBindings()
                  .value(allBindings().value().substr(0, valueAccessor()));
            }
        }
    }
```

```
  <textarea data-bind="value: message, 
                       maxLength: 255, 
                       valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not in the view do something like this:

```
<textarea data-bind="event: { keypress: enforceMaxlength }></textarea>
```

With this in the viewModel?

```
function enforceMaxlength(data, event) {
        if (event.target.value.length >= maxlength) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute maxlength for textarea.

For your problem, I found a way without any function:

```
<textarea style="resize: none;" data-bind="value: payComments, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { maxlength: payCommentsMaxlength }"></textarea>
```

```
 var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.payCommentsMaxlength = "20";
  self.payComments = ko.observable("");  
  
  self.payCommentsCountAndMax = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.payCommentsMaxlength - self.payComments().length;
  });
}

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I have a similar task, you could look through it here: http://jsfiddle.net/KateKotova/h9cvj38L/12/